# Three.js and Animated GIF

Tags: javascript, three.js, animated-gif

I have been trying to work with http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/ the last few days in order to incorporate a 4 frame animated gif into the loadTexture function of a canvas-based, six-sided mesh.

Any thoughts or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Three.js, but all jsgif does is parse the animated GIF into frames and then display them on a canvas. This seems to be independent of that, and if you're dealing with your own animation, you're much better off splitting it into static frames in advance and then using whatever animation facility Three.js has using those frames. You're not going to get anything for free from the browser's animated GIF support.